# jQuery only applied on one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My problem is that i have an agenda where i want the same functionality on each button i have this wordpress code but the jQuery only applies to the first one. I made a jsfiddle you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/m5nxkqcj/

## Wordpress

```
<?php 

        $posts = get_field('agenda_relationship');

            if( $posts ): ?>

                    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
                    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

                    <a id="agendabutton" class="large-12 small-12 columns"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                    <?php if( have_rows('agenda') ): ?>

                                <?php while( have_rows('agenda') ): the_row(); ?>

                                    <div id="agendatext"><?php the_sub_field('start_time'); ?> - <?php the_sub_field('end_time'); ?> - <?php the_sub_field('agenda_description'); ?></div>

                                <?php endwhile; ?>

                            <?php endif; ?>


                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

now i run this

## jQuery

```
jQuery(function($) {

$('#agendabutton').click(function() {
$('#agendatext').slideToggle(500);

})

});
```

But as you can see in the jsfiddle only one slide is applied, what causes this and how to make it work? http://jsfiddle.net/m5nxkqcj/

Comment: Hey, Ids are supposed to be unique in a web page...

Comment: `#` means an Id, which should be unique. jQuery therefore only looks for the first encounter. Use classes instead

Comment: `IDs` are unique, so if your selector is pointing to an element's `id`, it will return just one element. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Thanks alot :) that worked, dont know why i it slipped my mind ! thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You should not duplicate ID's, they must be unique. Use classes instead to target multiple elements.

New HTML:

```
<a class="agendabutton" class="large-12 small-12 columns">Day one</a>
<div class="agendatext">08:00 - 9:15 - Her vil vi byde velkommen og spise lækker mogenmads buffet</div>

<a class="agendabutton" class="large-12 small-12 columns">Day Two</a>
<div class="agendatext">08:00 - 9:15 - Her vil vi byde velkommen og spise lækker mogenmads buffet</div>
```

Javascript code also changes a little. You don't want to toggle all `$('.agendatext')` but only the one following currently clicked button.

```
$('.agendabutton').click(function () {
    // for this currently clicked .agendabutton toggle next .agendatext
    $(this).next('.agendatext').slideToggle();
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m5nxkqcj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Change the id `agendabutton` to the class and it will work. :)